# string encoding error from delphi 7 to xe

Tags: string, delphi, encryption, aes, delphi-xe

i found on internet some source for crypt string and i saw that on delphi 7 the string is crypted and decrypted well, and when i try to do the same things with delphi xe2,xe3,xe4,xe5 the encryption end decryption fail with this error "invalid buffer size for decryption"

i'm using aes.pas and eiaes.pas from here: http://code.google.com/p/jalphi-lib/source/browse/trunk/codemyth/delphi/dontuseit/?r=7

i think that the problem is the enconding of string.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: You must use a UNICODE capable encryption library like [`Delphi Encryption Compendium (DEC)`](http://code.google.com/p/delphidec/)

Comment: there is no such type as string, it is a shortcut to some real type. in Delphi 7 string is pointing to AnsiString, in Delphi XE2 it is shortcut to UnicodeString (and in Delphi 1 was shortcut for ShortString). Same goes for char and PChar (AnsiChar or WideChar respectively).  Fix your code and library code by replacing char/PChar/string jokers (different in different Delphi versions) with chosen and fixed real types.

Comment: You need to read the documentation and understand your compiler. Since Delphi 2009, Char is aliased to WideChar and is a 16 bit type.

Comment: you can also take ready-made and maintained AES implementations from Spring For Delphi [tag:spring4d] or Lockbox [tag:lockbox-3] libraries. However any encryption works with binary data and you would have choose some same real data representation for any Delphi version - but at least this choice would not be hidden from you and you would know what you're doing.

Comment: Nice path in that repository, `dontuseit` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AES library you provided the link to has not been updated to support the fact that "**String**" in later versions of Delphi (Delphi 2009 onward) is now a **UnicodeString** where each character is a **WideChar**.

You have 4 options:

1. Contact the library author and ask if a Unicode version is
   planned/available
2. Attempt to modify the library to support Unicode yourself (or find
   someone who can/will help do this)
3. Find an alternative encryption library that already supports Unicode
4. Ensure that you only use ANSI Strings with the library.

This last option may not be viable for you but if it is then you will still need to modify the AES library, but you will not need to do any code changes.

The problem is that "**String**" and "**Char**" in the later versions of Delphi are "*Wide*" types (2 bytes per 'character').  This difference is almost certainly causing problems with code in the AES library that assumes only **ONE** byte per character.

You can make these assumptions valid by making sure that the AES code is working with ANSI Strings.

If you choose to do this, then I would suggest that you introduce two new types:

```
type
  AESString = ANSIString;
  AESChar   = ANSIChar;
  PAESChar  = ^AESChar;
```

You will then need to go through the AES library code replacing any reference to "**String**" with "**AESString**", "**Char**" with "**AESChar**" and "**PChar**" with "**PAESChar**".

This should then make AES an ANSI String library and it will still be usable in Delphi 7 (i.e. pre-Delphi 2009) if that's important for you.

If you then find in the future that you do need to fully support Unicode strings and then need to properly fix the AES library code itself, you can do this and then simply change the **AESString** and **AESChar** types to:

```
type
  AESString = String;
  AESChar   = Char;
```

If this is then compiled with a non-Unicode version of Delphi, the library will automatically revert back to ANSI String ("**String**" == **ANSIString** pre-D2009), so your Unicode changes will need to take this into account if you need to support both Unicode and non-Unicode versions of Delphi.  You do need to be careful, but this is not difficult.

Comment: yes, in delphi 7 continue to work after replacing all reference, but all conversion continue to be wrong now with newer delphi version

Comment: I tested this with Delphi 2006 (ANSI Strings, like Delphi 7) and with Delphi 2010 (Unicode Strings).  After making the suggested changes I get consistent results from EncryptString() whether passing an ANSIString, String or WideString variable (which will be automatically converted to ANSIString for processing by the AES code) in both Delphi 2006 and 2010.  If you are getting different results then you perhaps haven't changed all the String, Char and PChar references to AESString, AESChar and AESPChar.   fyi:  I found that there were no "Char" references, but there were String and PChar.

Comment: You might be interested in my blog post where I describe using a test case to verify and validate changes made to the AES library to make it a strict ANSI library.  http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/2006